# Pandas: read_csv() method: string length limit

Tags: python, pandas, readline

I have a file with millions of lines (26Gb).
But the second line has 23,000,000 of `b'\x00'` symbols (NUL).
When I read from a file into DataFrame it fails to read the second line, so I received only one line.

1. Is there any possibility to read all data with read_csv method?
2. Is there any difference between 1.3.5 and 1.1.4 versions of Pandas?
   Surprisingly, it reads the full data with 1.1.4 version.

Comment: there is no length limit. It isn't exactly clear what you mean by "`b'\x00` symbols".

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052052/how-to-read-a-csv-with-rows-of-nul-x00-into-pandas) might be helpful. Process them out ahead of time and let pandas read the resulting data

Comment: Give `pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=[1])` a shot

Comment: @C.Nivs Unfortunately, it is not possible to clean the file, because I can't read the long line even with simple and straightforward readline() or readlines() methods.

Comment: @IvanVodopyanov You could read it in chunks by opening in `rb` mode and stripping out NUL bytes in the loop by doing a `chunk.replace(b'\x00', b'')` for each chunk and joining them together into a cleaned file

Comment: @C.Nivs is it possible to join chunks into a 26Gb line? Will it raise a `Memory Error`?

Comment: If you are concerned about the 26GB *line* causing memory problems, I have bad news about the dataframe processing your 26GB file

Comment: This is one of those few cases where maybe a screenshot would be helpful? What does this crazy file actually look like...

Answer (score 0):

As an illustration of a comment I made, you could transform the file ahead of time to strip out NUL bytes by reading in chunks at a time:

```py
import partial
import pandas


# Open two files, your original and a new file
with open("somehugefile.csv", 'rb') as infile, open('transformed.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    # Iterate in 100000 byte chunks, rather than line-by-line
    for chunk in iter(partial(infile.read, 100000), b''):
        # write the transformed content to the new file
        outfile.write(chunk.replace(b'\x00', b''))


# then process your new file instead
df = pd.read_csv('transformed.csv')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working: I receive no data after enormous segment of NULLs.

Comment: @IvanVodopyanov It sounds like maybe your file is just 26GB of null bytes, then