# Some columns break csv reading with pandas and make the whole output table filled with NA

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv export-file that I cannot change beforehand and I try to read it with Python (pandas), yet I usually got the df with "Unnamed" columns and "NA" instead all values.

The columns of csv file look like: `['Number','Date', 'Recipient 1', 'Recipient 2', 'Comment', 'Amount', 'Currency']`. Columns `Recipient 1` and `Recipient 2` are competely blank.

And reading it with `pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='cp1252')` I get:

```
N  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ...  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7
0   NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
3   NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

(encoding and delimiters used are correct).
I've identified that columns `Recipient 1` and `Recipient 2` cause problem. Since:

1. If I remove them, it works;
2. If I fill them with values. it works
3. If I keep them empty, but rename manually in something different (e.g., `Recipient` and `Recipientq`), it works

`usecolumns` method does not work, since it does not identify column names in a faulty file.

The question is, what could I do to make sure I load the file correctly? I do not need to keep those columns, but I need to somehow edit them to enable loading correctly.

edit: `header=none, skiprows=1` will yield similar:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Try other parameters like: `pd.read_csv(..., header=None, skiprows=1, names=['Number','Date', 'Comment', 'Amount', 'Currency'])`

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention it - it will yield same result, just with numbers instead of " Unnamed" column names. Or the ones I specify in the `names`. I will add it to the topic

Comment: Can you provide an example of your csv file, please?

Comment: @Corralien unfortunately no, since it contains sensitive infos. Yet it gave me another observation - I opened it with Excel (to remove sensitive data for example), re-saved it and afterwards it works. It works also if I do not change anything, just re-save a file before loading in pandas. Not a feasible solution to the problem of course...

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052349/5874325

Turned out was that NULL characted problem. Adapted function from the answer:

```
def import_file(filename):
    # open the file and clean it
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = list(f.readlines())

        # replace NUL, strip whitespace from the end of the strings, split each string into a list
        d = [v.replace('\x00', '').strip().split(';') for v in d]

        # remove some empty rows
        d = [v for v in d if len(v) > 2]

    # load the file with pandas
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    
    return df
```